# What happens if the same static member variable has different values

Tags: c++

**1.cc**

```
struct foo{
  const static int bar = 5;
};

int main(){
 return foo::bar;
}
```

**2.cc**

```
struct foo{
  const static int bar = 6;
};
```

`g++ 1.cc 2.cc` doesn't give a link error.
Does this go against the *one definition rule* and cause undefined behaviour?

Additionally i'm not sure why `const int foo::bar;` was not even needed as suggested by this article: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=members-static-data
which says:

> Note that the constant initializer is not a definition. You still need to define the static member in an enclosing namespace.

But mine compiles with or without it.

Comment: Just making sure, you compiled with all warnings turned on (`-Wall`)?

Comment: *Does this go against the one definition rule and cause undefined behaviour?* Yes.  You have two different definitions of the same type, which is more than the one you are allowed.

Comment: Would the linker even need to lookup any symbols from 2.cc, if the main is in 1.cc?

Comment: Yes, try the same with non-static global variables.

Comment: Unless the struct in 2.cpp is referenced from 1.cpp, it is a separate entity. There's no compilation error because it's valid code. You're creating two objects with the same "local" name, but they should wind up being two different objects in the link map. (That is very likely implementation-dependent and undefined behavior, BUT the behavior I'm describing is what I've witnessed. Doesn't mean that it's correct.)

Comment: Compiler can't catch it because they are defined in separate translation units. Linker probably can't catch it because the modern compiler will optimize it out, instead replacing all uses with one of the two different numbers directly and never leaving any traces for the linker to see.

Comment: (And this, kids, is why header files are stupid, and necessary.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are breaking the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule): Class definitions in multiple translation units have to be the same. This makes your program ill-formed, but compiler's don't have to warn you about it.

If you had multiple definitions (`const int foo::bar;`), you would probably run into a linker error. But without any definitions, it is difficult for the compiler to detect this at link time, so it just isn't.

In practice, if you had a definition in `1.cc`, you would find that usages in `1.cc` would always evaluate to 5, and in `2.cc` they would sometimes be `6` (always `6` in constant expressions) and sometimes be `5`.

---

The reason you don't need a definition to have `return foo::bar;` is that this does not [ODR-use](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) `foo::bar`, it is simply a constant expression that evaluates to `5` (without needing a definition of `foo::bar`). If you instead had something like:

```cpp
int copy(const int& x) {
    return x;
}

int main() {
    return copy(foo::bar);
}
```

Binding the reference `const int& x` would ODR-use `foo::bar`, and the linker would complain about there not being a definition for `foo::bar`.